# SQLiteException: Error inserting into database : syntax error (code 1)

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, sqlite

I believe the error lies in the way I have setup DATABASE_CREATE. Am I missing something here? I'm getting SQLiteException where long id = -1. Let me know if I am providing enough details. I've tried setting KEY_ID = "_id";

```
E/SQLiteLog(2385): (1) near "group": syntax error
E/SQLiteDatabase(2385): Error inserting group=demo
E/SQLiteDatabase(2385): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "group": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO groups(group) VALUES (?)
LOG(2385): Inserting record...
LOG(2385): mGroupName = demo
LOG(2385): long id = -1
```

**DBAdapter.java**

```
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_GROUP_NAME = "group";
public static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "GroupsDB";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "groups";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table if not exists groups (id integer primary key autoincrement, group VARCHAR not null);";
```

.
.
.

```
//---insert a record into the database
public long insertRecord(String group) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_GROUP_NAME, group);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);  
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
EditText groupNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.groupNameEditText);
String mGroupname = groupNameText.getText().toString();
```

...

```
                try {
                    String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/GroupsDB";
                    File f = new File(destPath);
                    if(!f.exists()) {
                        CopyDB( getBaseContext().getAssets().open("mydb"),
                        new FileOutputStream(destPath));
                    }
                }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

                //try hard coding the record here, if unable to insertRecord for any reason it will return -1
                db.open();
                long id = db.insertRecord(mGroupname);
                Log.i(TAG, "Inserting record...");
                Log.i(TAG, "mGroupName = " + mGroupname);
                Log.i(TAG, "long id = " + id);
                db.close();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

group is a SQLite keyword. See: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Change all references to "group" to something like "mgroup"

Comment: I wasted about a hour trying to figure out what's wrong with my table name "group" :) who would thought.

Comment: Like @Hades200621... I've wasted more than an hour without knowing what is going on... Thanks @KlassAktKreations!